# How to vertically align image

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am attempting to vertically align an image in a div, but everything I try won't work.

I am attempting to center it in a [material design lite](https://getmdl.io/) cell.

Here is my code:

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/shaansheikh/pen/XKyVgP)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
  a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div class="imgholder">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8EX.png" id="stackimg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.mdl-cell{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.imgholder{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
#stackimg{
  width:50%;
  float: right;
  position: reletive;
  top:50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`Vertical-align: middle` isn't doing anything. Neither is `top: 50%`. The image does have a parent div with a defined height, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it won't fix your problem, but mind your spelling - relative, not reletive

Comment: A great guide for centering in CSS, should fix all your problems: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: position must be fixed or absolute to use `top`.

Comment: @RemcovanOs Already saw that before posting. None of the methods worked for me. See the codepen linked in the OP

Comment: @quantumbutterfly I need to center: Vertically - block-level element - unknown height (percentage counts as unknown) -  Works in the CodePen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vertically center your image by using [`translateY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY). Give your container a `position: relative;` and then assign `position: absolute;` along with `transform: translateY(-50%);` to your image.

**CSS**

```
.imgholder{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#stackimg{
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/NAEXrv)**

Comment: Or if you want the image to keep `position: relative` add a `left: 50%` and the `transform`

Answer (score 0):

Vertical align your div containing image instead  of the img tag itself, or 
check this:

```
> `http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: I've already seen and tried that. That's not working either. I suspect the css for mdl is somehow interfering